# Does convergence in $L^p$ and pointwise imply the same limit?

Tags: measure-theory

If $f_n\in L^p$ converge to $f$ pointwise and to $g$ in $L^p$. Does that mean $f=g$ almost everywhere?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Hint: convergence in $L^p$ implies the existence of a subsequence converging pointwise a.e. See corollary 7.11 [here](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch7.pdf).

Answer (score 8):

As julien suggest, since $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$, there exist a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ which converges pointwise almost everywhere to $f$. But since $f_n\to g$ pointwise 
it follows that $f_{n_k}\to g$ pointwise.

So, in the set of pointwise convergence of $f_{n_k}\to f$ we must have $f = g$. Therefore $f = g$ almost everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

By Fatou's lemma, we have $$\int \liminf_{n \to \infty} |f_n-f|^p d\mu \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int |f_n-f|^p d\mu.$$
Since $f_n$ converges to g pointwisely, we have
$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} |f_n-f|^p=\lim_{n \to \infty} |f_n-f|^p=|g-f|^p.$$
Also, $f_n$ converges to f in $L_p$, then
$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} \int |f_n-f|^p d\mu=\lim_{n \to \infty} \int |f_n-f|^p d\mu=0.$$
Therefore, we have
$$\int |g-f|^p d\mu=0,$$
which implies that $g=f$ almost everywhere.